# How can I change this data to javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm using node.js rest to send data to server.

In client page, I make my data as JavaScript object and put in to
`ajax.post` to send to server.

In server page, when I console.log that data.

I can't view data as data.key because it has ' '.
How can I get that data as JavaScript object or how can I
handle data from key???

My client side code is

```
var checkedArr = [];
var __thing = {};

$("input[name=box]:checked").each(function (index) {
    checkedArr.push($(this).context.value);
    __thing[index] = $(this).context.value;
});

$.post('/channel/remove', __thing, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and I got this data from

```
    function remove(lcode, req, res, chDB) {

    console.log(typeof req.body);

    var data = (req.body);
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);

    var jtext = '{"name":"yaho"}';
    jtext = JSON.parse(jtext);
    console.log(jtext);


    //var _id = this.getRequestBody(req, '_id');

    //chDB.remove({_id:{$in:}})

    //chDB.remove({_id: _thing}, function (err, result) {
    //    console.log(result);
    //    console.log(result.result.n);
    //    res.json({code: (result.result.n == 1) ? 200 : 404});
    //});
    }
```

and server console's like

```
    object
    { '0': '5', '1': '6', '2': '7' }
    {"0":"5","1":"6","2":"7"}
    { '0': '5', '1': '6', '2': '7' }
    { name: 'yaho' }
    object
    { '0': '5', '1': '6', '2': '7' }
    {"0":"5","1":"6","2":"7"}
    { '0': '5', '1': '6', '2': '7' }
    { name: 'yaho' }
```

Comment: Could you please show us what exactly the client code is sending to the server? You can inspect the network tab in Chrome Developer Tools (by pressing F12) or use FireBug (for Firefox) and add it to the question, so it becomes clearer if the issue is in the client or the server.

Comment: You have to use the `dataType` attribute in your post [look here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data.key['index']` for accessing individual elements.